# Getting value from dynamically generated basicEditField in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, user-interface, java-me

I am developing an app where I need to generate a dynamic `EditField`. I am able to generate this, but when I try to get a value from these fields I get the value of last `EditField` generated in the screen for all fields.

I am pasting some J2ME code below, but I do not know how to get the same effect with BlackBerry API calls.

```
EditField ef;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  EditField ef = new EditField("Name : "+i, "");
  add(ef);
  add(new SeparatorField());
} 


for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
  System.out.println(""+ef.getText());
}
```

---

```
private TextField fld, fld1;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  fld = new TextField("Name :", null, 30, TextField.ANY);
  append(fld);
}


for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  fld1 = (TextField) this.get(i);
  System.out.println(""+fld1.getString());
}
```

Comment: create array of fields. then add that array to your screen.

Comment: @BlackPearl I am using Blackberry Eclipse plugins 7.0.1 and I tried to create the Array of Fields but it was not working. I tried like this. public List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>(); but it seems 7.0.1 does not supports this. You can use the same syntax in 5.0 or below.Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I got my problem Solved. This answer is for those who are interested in it.

EditField ef;
Hashtable allEds = new Hashtable();

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
             EditField ef = new EditField("Name : "+i, "");
             add(ef);
             add(new SeparatorField());
             allEds.put(""+i, ef);
            } 


Enumeration e = allEds.elements();

while(e.hasMoreElements()){
                System.out.println(""+e.nextElement().toString());

            }
```